# How to Get return ID from SQL exec

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an SQL exec in stored procedure like this

```
DECLARE 
    @SQLQuery   NVARCHAR(max),  
    @table      NVARCHAR(max)

SET @table =  + 'log_'+ @idCampaign

SET @SQLQuery =
'DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(200); 

INSERT INTO ' + @table + ' ( campaignRowID, idCampaign, idUser )
    VALUES( ''' + @campaignRowID + ''', ''' + @idCampaign + ''', ''' + @idUser + ''' )

SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 

exec InsertData '''+ convert(nvarchar, @idCampaign) + ''',''' + convert(nvarchar, @ID) + ''''

exec (@SQLQuery)
```

i can get the `@ID` but can't use it for another execute SP btw `@ID` is `nvarchar`,

How i can get the return `ID` and use it for another execute sp?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly is failing, and what the error message is?

Comment: i don't know where is the mistake, but the @ID at exec InsertData is empty

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit because the question is lacking detail, but I think your issue may be with how you're attempting to use the `@ID` variable.

Because `@ID` is declared inside the scope of the dynamic SQL statement, it's only accessible inside that scope.

The problem might be that on this line, you're attempting to use `@ID` as if it were declared outside the scope of the dynamic SQL:

```
exec InsertData '''+ convert(nvarchar, @idCampaign) + ''',''' + convert(nvarchar, @ID) + ''''
```

Instead, reference `@ID` inside the scope of the statement:

```
exec InsertData '''+ convert(nvarchar, @idCampaign) + ''',@ID'
```

**EDIT**

I created the following to test the code; it appears to work for me

```
CREATE TABLE log_100 (id INT IDENTITY, campaignRowId VARCHAR(100), idCampaign VARCHAR(100), idUser VARCHAR(100))
GO
CREATE PROC InsertData
@idCampaign VARCHAR(100),
@id NVARCHAR(200)
AS

SELECT @idCampaign ic, @id id
GO

    declare @idCampaign varchar(100) = '100'
    declare @campaignRowID varchar(100) = '200'
    declare @idUser varchar(100) = '200'

DECLARE 
    @SQLQuery   NVARCHAR(max),  
    @table      NVARCHAR(max)

SET @table =  + 'log_'+ @idCampaign

SET @SQLQuery =
'DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(200); 

INSERT INTO ' + @table + ' ( campaignRowID, idCampaign, idUser )
    VALUES( ''' + @campaignRowID + ''', ''' + @idCampaign + ''', ''' + @idUser + ''' )

SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
exec InsertData '''+ convert(nvarchar, @idCampaign) + ''',@ID'

exec (@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: it give error 
exec InsertData '''+ convert(nvarchar, @idCampaign) + ''',@ID' is not a valid identifier. the @ID not change into the return id

Comment: @MIke - I added up a complete working example with a dummy target table and stored procedure.